# What is $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k!(p-k)!$ mod $p$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, modular-arithmetic

I would like to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k!(p-k)!$ mod $p$ is equivalent to the negative of the multiplicative inverse of $2$ mod $p$.

I know that $k!(p-k)!\equiv k(-1)^k$ mod $p$. So $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k!(p-k)!=1!(p-1)!+2!(p-2)!+\cdot\cdot\cdot+(p-1)!(p-p+1)!$ mod $p$

$\equiv 1(-1)^1+2(-1)^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+(p-1)(-1)^{p-1}$ mod $p$

$\equiv -1 + 2-3+\cdot\cdot\cdot+(p-1)$ mod $p$

This is where I am stuck, any hints would be helpful.

Comment: Then isn't it simply (p-1)/2 mod p?

Comment: Shouldn't you multiply your number by $2$ and see whether the result is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$?

Comment: are you sure this is correct ? for example, take $p=3$, then we have $1!.2!+2!.1!=4$ which is not an inverse of $2$ mod $3$.

Comment: @seeker sorry it should say the negative multiplicative inverse of 2 mod $p$.

Comment: @guest I was thinking about how to get to (p-1)/2. Should I be looking at the number of terms I have in order to do this? I know that I have p - 1 terms, so it would make sense that it might follow from this, but I'm not sure.

Comment: -1 and +2 cancels out to 1, so does -3 and +4 and so on, and the number of such pairs is (p-1)/2. EDIT: I assumed that p is odd number here, and the problem is not true for $p=2$ anyway.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: from [finite calculus](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dgleich/publications/Gleich%202005%20-%20finite%20calculus.pdf) we have that

$$\sum (-1)^k k\;\delta k=(-1)^k\frac{1}{-2}k-\sum(-1)^{k+1}\frac1{-2}\delta k=\\=\frac{k}2(-1)^{k+1}-\frac14(-1)^{k+1}=(-1)^{k+1}\left(\frac{2k-1}4\right)$$

Hence

$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(-1)^kk=\sum\nolimits_1^p(-1)^kk\;\delta k=(-1)^{k+1}\left(\frac{2k-1}4\right)\bigg|_1^p=\frac{2p-1}{4}(-1)^{p+1}-\frac14$$

For $p$ odd we have

$$\frac{2p-1}{4}(-1)^{p+1}-\frac14=\frac{2p-2}{4}=\frac{p-1}2$$

For $p$ even we have

$$\frac{2p-1}{4}(-1)^{p+1}-\frac14=-\frac{p}2$$